# How to only send certain properties of a class as json

Tags: json, grails

I have a simple action such as this:

```
def showSomething() {
   render Color.get(params.id) as JSON
}
```

This will render all the properties in the Color class as JSON. However, what if I only want to render two properties, say, `colorName and shade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gjordis has the right option if you want to render the same properties everytime you render the object. However, you could simply do this:

```
Color color = Color.get(params.id)
render ([colorName: color.colorName, shade: color.shade] as JSON)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple:

```
def relevantProperties = ["colorName","shade"]
def color = Color.get(params.id)
def reply = relevantProperties.collectEntries { property ->
    [property, color[property]]
}

render reply as JSON
```

and there you are :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
import grails.converters.JSON
class BootStrap {
    def init = {servletContext ->
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Color) {
            def returnArray = [:]
            returnArray['shade'] = it.shade
            returnArray['colorName'] = it.colorName
            return returnArray
    }
```

}

Somebody can correct me, I have not used grails. But overriding the function called in the conversion is the key.

Comment: this lacks a certain flexibility, doesn't it?

Comment: It registers the converter to a class. You only need to do it once. After that it returns the same values each time you call render ... as JSON