# How to remove field from JSON in Grails

Tags: json, grails, get

I have implemented domain class:

```
package xxx

class Machine {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and I also have got a service:

```
package xxx

import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.json.simple.JSONObject


@Path('/api/machine')
class MachineService {

    @GET
    @Produces(['application/json'])
    def String readAll() {
        Machine.findAll() as JSON
    }
}
```

and the output is:

> [{"class":"xxx.Machine","id":1,"name":"test1"},{"class":"xxx.Machine","id":2,"name":"test2"},{"class":"xxx.Machine","id":3,"name":"test3"}]

I would like to remove field "class". Could you show me the easiest way to reach this goal ?

Comment: Do you always want to remove class when this is converted to JSON or just in this instance?

Comment: I have got plenty domains and I want to remove this field from all domains.

Comment: If you are talking about across domains, you may need to extend the JSON converter to always exclude it.

Comment: Could you explain me how? I am looking for the easiest solution. Let's assume that I want to remove this field only from domain Machine, right ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565219/how-to-only-send-certain-properties-of-a-class-as-json/16566041#16566041

Comment: It looks good, but I only want to remove one field...grails does not support it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175286/custom-string-formatting-in-grails-json-marshaller/8186689#8186689). Just register custom marshaller and remove **class** property from all rendered classes

**Update:**
Change excluded properties like this: `String[] excludedProperties=['metaClass','class']`

Comment: how can I remove class property ?

Comment: Have you read the answer? The full description is here. Change excluded properties like this: String[] excludedProperties=['metaClass','class'] and thats it.

Comment: Eh, sorry...I had been trying plenty solutions before I tried this one. After quick nap I read your post again and of course, it works :)